# How to parse my log.txt in this format in java

Tags: java

I am trying to parse this certain log entry

> "[Zone] ZoneChangeList.ProcessChanges() - processing index=9
>   change=powerTask=[power=[type=TAG_CHANGE entity=[id=78 cardId=FP1_007t
>   name=Nerubian] tag=IGNORE_DAMAGE_OFF value=1] complete=False]
>   entity=[name=Nerubian id=78 zone=GRAVEYARD zonePos=1 cardId=FP1_007t
>   player=2] srcZoneTag=INVALID srcPos= dstZoneTag=INVALID dstPos=";

I am using a scanner delimiter in Java but the problem is that the change field 
which has multiple values enclosed in a bracket.

I would also want to put the parsed record on a bean having their values

So far, here is what I have coded:

```
  public class HearthstoneParser {
       public void zoneParser(String line) {
          Scanner scanner = new Scanner(line);
          scanner.useDelimiter(" ");
          while (scanner.hasNext()) {
          System.out.println(scanner.next());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String zoneString = "[Zone] ZoneChangeList.ProcessChanges() - processing index=9          change=powerTask=[power=[type=TAG_CHANGE entity=[id=78 cardId=FP1_007t name=Nerubian] tag=IGNORE_DAMAGE_OFF value=1] complete=False] entity=[name=Nerubian id=78 zone=GRAVEYARD zonePos=1 cardId=FP1_007t player=2] srcZoneTag=INVALID srcPos= dstZoneTag=INVALID dstPos=";
        HearthstoneParser parser = new HearthstoneParser();
        parser.zoneParser(zoneString);
    }
   }
```

I would want to keep them organized that they are group with their brackets respectively 
sample output would be:

```
Zone

 event = ZoneChangeList.ProcessChanges()

 index = 9

 change 
    powerTask 
        power 
      type = TAG_CHANGE
          entity
              id = 78
              cardID=Fp1_007t
          name Nerubian
          tag=IGNORE_DAMAGE_OFF
          value=1
        complete=False

  entity
      name=nerubian
      id=78
      zone=GRAVEYARD
      zonePos=1
      cardId=FP1_007t
      player=2

  srcZoneTag=INVALID
  srcPos=
  dstZoneTag=INVALID
  dstPos=
```

Comment: Could you add your desired output?

Comment: It might work to just use a json parser that can configure delimiters and brackets.

Comment: I would like to parse it with something like this                      Zone

 event = ZoneChangeList.ProcessChanges()

 index = 9

 change 
    powerTask 
        power 
   type = TAG_CHANGE
          entity
              id = 78
              cardID=Fp1_007t
          name Nerubian
          tag=IGNORE_DAMAGE_OFF
          value=1
        complete=False

  entity
      name=nerubian
      id=78
      zone=GRAVEYARD
      zonePos=1
      cardId=FP1_007t
      player=2

  srcZoneTag=INVALID
  srcPos=
  dstZoneTag=INVALID
  dstPos=